# How to make VoiceOver cursor scroll my webpage visually?

Tags: scroll, focus, accessibility, html, voiceover

When a person is exploring my webpage via Voiceover (flicking from element to element on a phone, or Control-Option-right/left arrow on a desktop), I want the screen to scroll so that whatever VoiceOver is reading is also visible.

What happens right now is that on a long screen full of only text (on Mac with Chrome 52), the Voiceover cursor will continue off-screen, and the screen will only update its visual scroll position when the cursor encounters something interactive like a link or an input field.  You can try it for yourself here: https://www.apple.com/voiceover/info/guide/_1128.html

I saw an answer to a similar question about native apps, that people using Swift etc needed to manage the scrolling themselves.  Is it the same for websites?  Is JavaScript the only way to manage Voiceover focus scrolling?

Comment: It might help to understand *why* you want it to scroll. Do you have lazy loading that is not working? Is there some control that behaves differently only when in the viewport?

Comment: Just for accessibility; some people use Voiceover to help them read a page, but can still see, and might find it confusing that Voiceover was talking about stuff that they don't see on the page at all.

Comment: From experience, sighted VO users are aware and manually scroll the page as they go. If you have real user testing showing this is an issue then it is worth addressing, but barring that be careful about making assumptions and accidentally creating a problematic interface in an effort to help.